# What exactly is "enough", when defining whether or not a nomination fails and an election is cancelled?

Tags: support, moderator-election

The nomination page says (emphasis added):

> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to the primary phase. However, if there are 10 or fewer candidates, we skip directly to the election phase. **If there are not enough eligible nominations at the end of the nomination period, it will be extended by one week. If there are not enough nominations after an extension the election will be canceled.**

What exactly does "enough" mean here?

I assume less than 30, since with just 10, the nomination phase can still pass on, skipping the primary phase. And for the same reason, I assume less than 10... But what exactly is the threshold?

Comment: in some smaller elections, they've been allowed to "succeed" with as little as 2 candidates for filling 1 position. Of course, with just two candidates, calling up the second later is a bit awkward

Comment: I understand it basically as "not enough candidates to fill the open positions"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Enough eligible nominations" means at least one more nomination than moderator slots available in the election. So, for the [current 2024-02/03 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) with two slots available, at least 3 people must have active nominations at the end of the nomination period.